# CollabnetSVN (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified. : AH00436: No installed service named "CollabNet Subversion Server"

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

After setup [CollabNet Subversion Edge](https://www.collab.net/products/subversion) with all default setting, I can't start the server, check the log, I have this "AH00436: No installed service named "CollabNet Subversion Server". Look in the services (mmc.exe) I found that there is only a service with name "CollabNet Subversion Edge" instead of "CollabNet Subversion Server". Any clue to solve this problem are appreciated!

P/s : I have a very little with the system management things!

Here is my logs:

```
14:12.612084 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 4188:tid 124] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00436: No installed service named "CollabNet Subversion Server".



2013-06-27 16:14:12,612 [qtp975952-62] WARN  console.LifecycleService  - Server start attempt failed with code=2

2013-06-27 16:14:12,612 [qtp975952-62] WARN  console.LifecycleService  - Output:

2013-06-27 16:32:43,356 [qtp975952-62] ERROR console.CommandLineService  - Exit status=2 Process err output: [Thu Jun 27 16:32:43.340971 2013] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 7056:tid 124] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00436: No installed service named "CollabNet Subversion Server".



2013-06-27 16:32:43,356 [qtp975952-62] WARN  console.LifecycleService  - Server start attempt failed with code=2

2013-06-27 16:32:43,356 [qtp975952-62] WARN  console.LifecycleService  - Output:
```

Comment: Have you tried to 'Repair' through **Control Panel | Programs and Features**?

Comment: Yes, bug it didn't help!

Answer (score 1):

Along with "CollabNet Subversion Edge" 3 more services got created during installation

Which looks something like this and point to mentioned location depending upon the installation directory :

**"CollabNet Subversion Apache**" >> "D:\SVN\CollabNet\SubversionServer\httpd\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice

"**CollabNet Subversion Server**" >> "D:\csvn\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice

"**CollabNet Subversion svnserve**" >> "D:\SVN\CollabNet\SubversionServer\svnserve.exe" --service -r "D:\svn_repository" --listen-port "3690"

As suggested above either you can go for repair or can try reinstallation of the application .